why is my Mime Version not working properly
Users are not receiving emails
on my site, users are suppose to receive an activation code after resgitration but they are not receivng it.
This is the header i am currently using
$header = array();
    $header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $header[] = "From: {$domain}<{$adminemail}>";
    $header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";


There is nowhere near enough information to go on here. These headers are fine, but they tell us nothing about the rest of your script or the infrastructure you're running it on. The first thing you should do is look in your mail server logs.
